# Windows 10 upgrade stuck at 'Starting Download'

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade a Windows 8 domain computer to Windows 10.

I have set the domain user as an Administrator on the computer and then started the upgrade process using the upgrade icon next to the time but it has been stuck on 'Starting Download' for over 2 days.

I have searched online and tried many suggestions but none that seem to help. I have tried using the Media Creation Tool but that didn't work either (came up with some message that I'm not eligable to upgrade, even though I have the upgrade icon next to the time and I know that I am actually eligible) at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/wont-complete-starting-download-for-windows-10/01012825-e274-48b1-9482-9643369065f0?auth=1.

[image]

I'm out of ideas now and continued searching online leads me to suggestions that I've already tried without much success.

### Update

I've managed to get to the 'Preparing to install' phase when then resulted in a "Check your PC before upgrading" error message. I clicked the button and there are no further messages to guide me on what to do.

Now I'm back to square one, with no download or installation happening.

Comment: Are you the Domain Administrator also? Updates may be blocked by the domain which you may be running into.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin Updates aren't blocked, I have done the same thing on other computers, but yes I am a Domain Administrator.

Comment: @user6219126 Do you use another Windows interface language other than English ?

Comment: @iSR5 No I don't.

Comment: @user6219126 have you tried this solution? : http://www.alphr.com/microsoft/1001411/how-to-fix-windows-update-in-windows-10-if-it-becomes-stuck

Comment: @iSR5 Yes I have already been through each suggestion listed there (but I read them on other sites).

Comment: @user6219126 Which version of Windows do you have ? is it Home/Pro/ Enterprise ?

Comment: @iSR5 Windows 8.1 Pro with Media Center.

Comment: @user6219126 do a system restore to the date before you started the upgrade, then clean your windows from temp files..etc. After that do the command sfc /scannow using the command prompt as administrator. Next , restart your computer and go to this link and download the upgrade tool https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows10 and see how it goes.

Comment: @user6219126 you could download the tool and burn the iso into USB flash drive using another computer, but this will give you some errors in upgrading since your current system has some issues needs to be fixed. And to avoid that you either fix them first, or use the USB flash drive to do a clean install of Windows 10.

Comment: Run the compatibility report using the command prompt:  **schtasks.exe /Run /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience\Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser"**